# How to check if object of arrays is empty

Tags: javascript

I have an object like this:

```
{
  places: [],
  interests: [],
  checkIns: []
}
```

How can I easily check if any of those arrays are empty?

Comment: Loop over it and check the length?

Comment: `Object.keys(obj).filter(k => !obj[k].length).length > 0`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using ES6:

```
Object.values(obj).every(x => !x.length)
```

Returns true only if all the arrays of `obj` are empty.

Example:

```js
var obj = {
  places: [],
  interests: [],
  checkIns: []
}

console.log(Object.values(obj).every(x => !x.length));
```

```js
var obj = {
  places: [1],
  interests: [],
  checkIns: []
}

console.log(Object.values(obj).every(x => !x.length));
```

Comment: "if any of those arrays are empty" use some not every

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over the properties of your object by using `Object.entries` and `Array.prototype.forEach` and checking the length of the array, if the property is indeed an instance of `Array`.

```js
var o = {
  places: [],
  interests: [],
  checkIns: [],
  someItems: [1, 2, 3, 4],
  notArr: false
};

Object.entries(o).forEach(function(entry) {
  let [key, value] = entry;
  if (value instanceof Array) {
    if (value.length === 0) {
      console.log(`${key} is an empty array`);
    } else {
      console.log(`${key} is an array that contains items`);
    }
  } else {
    console.log(`${key} is not an array`);
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the properties using [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

> The `for...in` statement iterates over all non-[Symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol), [enumerable properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties) of an object.

For each iteration, you can check if any of the arrays have a `length` of 0.

Answer (score -1):

If you would like to check if **ANY** of the arrays in the *object of arrays* you have provided is empty, consider using [Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

*from MDN:*

> The some() method tests whether at least one element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function.

As your *object of arrays* is not an `Array` just yet, you must convert it into one first. For this case, use [Object.values():](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) **ex:** `let arrays = Object.values(objectOfArrays)`

*from MDN:*

> The Object.values() method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property values, in the same order as that provided by a for...in loop (the difference being that a for-in loop enumerates properties in the prototype chain as well).

Now that you have an `Array` of `Arrays`: `let arrays = [[], [], []]`, you can use `Array.some()`:

`arrays.some(array => !array.length)`

or:

```
arrays.some(function(array) {
  return !array.length
})
```

**Note** that specifying `array.length` by itself is just enough, instead of equalizing the whole way (`array.length === 0`). This is because `0` in a `Boolean` check in javascript (`if (condition) {...}`) returns `false`.

If the array had any value inside it, the `array.length` would should a number higher than `0`, which means calling `if (array.length) {...}` will return `true`

**PS:**
Calling `Array.every()` will be another approach. Although note that `Array.every()` iterates through **all** the values in an array, while `Array.some()` returns true once it meets your condition, and stops.

Comment: what if its an object then that would return true to !prop.length dont think this is the best way to handle

Comment: You have a good point for a general usecase... though pointless for the specific usecase stated

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.